# How to add loader in OPEN_GL

Tags: android, performance, opengl-es, 3d, uigesturerecognizer

I am implementing **OPENGL** by loading a **3D** images which is of **2.5MB** in my device it almost takes 3-4 mints, so I wanted to add a loader/progress-bar/progress-dialog in oncreate of the class. So that the user got response that device is loading the image and when it completes loading then dismiss that dialog box.

Here is my class

```
package com.example.objLoader;

import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.ByteOrder;
import java.nio.FloatBuffer;
import javax.microedition.khronos.egl.EGLConfig;
import javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL10;
import android.content.Context;
import android.opengl.GLSurfaceView;
import android.opengl.GLSurfaceView.Renderer;
import android.opengl.GLU;
import android.os.Debug;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ManishRenderer extends GLSurfaceView implements Renderer {
/** Triangle instance */
private OBJParser parser;
private TDModel model;

/* Rotation values */
private float xrot; // X Rotation
private float yrot; // Y Rotation

/* Rotation speed values */

private float xspeed; // X Rotation Speed ( NEW )
private float yspeed; // Y Rotation Speed ( NEW )

private float z = 700.0f;

private float oldX;
private float oldY;
private final float TOUCH_SCALE = 0.8f; // Proved to be good for normal rotation ( NEW )

private float[] lightAmbient = { 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f };
private float[] lightDiffuse = { 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f };
private float[] lightPosition = { 0.0f, -3.0f, 2.0f, 1.0f };
private FloatBuffer lightAmbientBuffer;
private FloatBuffer lightDiffuseBuffer;
private FloatBuffer lightPositionBuffer;

public ManishRenderer(Context ctx) {
    super(ctx); 
    Toast.makeText(ctx, "LOADING 3D IMAGE...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();       
    parser = new OBJParser(ctx);
    model = parser.parseOBJ("/storage/sdcard1/man.obj");        
    Debug.stopMethodTracing();
    this.setRenderer(this);
    this.requestFocus();
    this.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);     
    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "LOADING DONE...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    ByteBuffer byteBuf = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(lightAmbient.length * 5024);
    byteBuf.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    lightAmbientBuffer = byteBuf.asFloatBuffer();
    lightAmbientBuffer.put(lightAmbient);
    lightAmbientBuffer.position(0);
    byteBuf = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(lightDiffuse.length * 5024);
    byteBuf.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    lightDiffuseBuffer = byteBuf.asFloatBuffer();
    lightDiffuseBuffer.put(lightDiffuse);
    lightDiffuseBuffer.position(0);
    byteBuf = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(lightPosition.length * 5024);
    byteBuf.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    lightPositionBuffer = byteBuf.asFloatBuffer();
    lightPositionBuffer.put(lightPosition);
    lightPositionBuffer.position(0);
}

/**
 * The Surface is created/init()
 */
public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {
    gl.glLightfv(GL10.GL_LIGHT0, GL10.GL_AMBIENT, lightAmbientBuffer);
    gl.glLightfv(GL10.GL_LIGHT0, GL10.GL_DIFFUSE, lightDiffuseBuffer);
    gl.glLightfv(GL10.GL_LIGHT0, GL10.GL_POSITION, lightPositionBuffer);
    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_LIGHT0);
    gl.glShadeModel(GL10.GL_SMOOTH);
    gl.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.5f);
    gl.glClearDepthf(1.0f);
    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    gl.glDepthFunc(GL10.GL_LEQUAL);
    gl.glHint(GL10.GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL10.GL_NICEST);
}

/**
 * Here we do our drawing
 */
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
    // Clear Screen And Depth Buffer
    gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    gl.glLoadIdentity();
    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_LIGHTING);
    gl.glTranslatef(0.0f, -1.2f, -z); // Move down 1.2 Unit And Into The Screen 6.0
    gl.glRotatef(xrot, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f); // X
    gl.glRotatef(yrot, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f); // Y
    model.draw(gl); // Draw the square
    gl.glLoadIdentity();
    xrot += xspeed;
    yrot += yspeed;

}

/**
 * If the surface changes, reset the view
 */
public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {
    if (height == 0) { // Prevent A Divide By Zero By
        height = 1; // Making Height Equal One
    }

    gl.glViewport(0, 0, width, height); // Reset The Current Viewport
    gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION); // Select The Projection Matrix
    gl.glLoadIdentity(); // Reset The Projection Matrix

    // Calculate The Aspect Ratio Of The Window
    GLU.gluPerspective(gl, 45.0f, (float) width / (float) height, 0.1f,
            1100.0f);

    gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW); // Select The Modelview Matrix
    gl.glLoadIdentity(); // Reset The Modelview Matrix
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

    float x = event.getX();
    float y = event.getY();

    // If a touch is moved on the screen
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
        // Calculate the change
        float dx = x - oldX;
        float dy = y - oldY;
        // Define an upper area of 10% on the screen
        int upperArea = this.getHeight() / 10;

        // Rotate around the axis otherwise

        xrot += dy * TOUCH_SCALE;
        yrot += dx * TOUCH_SCALE;


        // A press on the screen
    } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {            
    }

    else if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN){            
    }

    else{           

    }

    // Remember the values
    oldX = x;
    oldY = y;

    // We handled the event
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    //
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_LEFT) {

    } else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_RIGHT) {

    } else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_UP) {
        z -= 3;

    } else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_DOWN) {
        z += 3;

    } else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER) {

    }

    // We handled the event
    return true;
}

}
```